# AWS Partner Accreditations on Resume

Tags: resume, linkedin, certification

My company is an AWS Partner, and so far I have completed the "AWS Technical Professional Accreditation" and was going to possibly do the Business one as well (there is also an economics one). I was wondering if anyone else put these accreditations on their resume/LinkedIn? Or if anyone has mentioned them to recruiters or an interview and it helped them in any way.

Comment: And what is AWS? Do you realize this is an international forum?

Comment: @JanDoggen Most likely, Amazon Web Services. But we need to be 100% sure and only the OP can close the loop on the uncertainty. If the OP doesn't clarify, I'll vote to close the question as vague/unclear. Like hell I am going to answer what I think a question is.

Comment: At any rate, whether you inlude this info depends upon whether this info is relevant to a prospective employer.If it isn't relevant - the best hint is that your prospective employers have no clue what the certification is let alone mean, then you're wasting space on your resume. Putting in info that's irrelevant on your resume will cost you points with your prospective employers because the info is distracting them. Putting in irrelevant info that they can't figure out may annoy them. Who knows what happens when they get annoyed.